# Swagger run locally but not on IIS, not resolving base path

Tags: json, iis, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am setting up Swagger for documenting my API.

I have set up the `SwaggerEndpoint` with a relative path the the specification json, like you see below:

[image: startup configuration]

When I debug locally, everything resolves fine. But my site just runs as `http://localhost:44348/index.html`.

When I deploy to IIS, which is on a virtual path, it blows apart:

[image: not resolving swagger.json]

1. Note that the URL in the browser has `/imaging4castapi_UAT/` as part of the path
2. Note that the actual request for the swagger.json is missing that base part of the path.

Here's what I've tried:

1. I tried removing the `RoutePrefix` override. But that doesn't resolve.
2. I tried using an application path like `"~/swagger/..."` but that's translated by the server on view elements like Razor pages and css and doesn't work here in `Startup`.

I'm struggling to understand if this is a client setup issue or something related to how my site is hosted on IIS.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, can you go to the network tab to see if maybe you can find an error?

Comment: Well the error is a 500 (probably cuz of routing) response because it's trying to find the `swagger.json` at a URL that doesn't exist. (see #2 on my second image)

Comment: I saw the image, but I got a similar error but I found more information on network tab, your second image is the console tab

Comment: This sounds ridiculous, but my colleague just removed the first forward slash (/) and that seemed to resolve all the issues... Ugh!

Answer (score 7):

Try using a relative path:

```
setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/Imaging4CastApiSpecification/swagger.json", "4Cast API");
```

Please note answer and explanation from the following issue: [SwashBuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/971)

Comment: Note that the actual solution for me was to simply remove the prefix slash. But the link to the documentation is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: this changes worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Swagger config for once of PRD application. Hope it helps

```cs
 public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerConfig(this IServiceCollection services, IHostingEnvironment env,
            string title, string version)
            => services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                //Ensure XML Document File of project is checked for both Debug and Release mode
                c.IncludeXmlComments("Your App.xml");
                //Display Enum name
                c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();

                //c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();

                    //Authentication for Bearer
                    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
                        new ApiKeyScheme
                        {
                            In = "header",
                            Description = "Please enter JWT with Bearer into field",
                            Name = "Authorization",
                            Type = "apiKey"
                        });

                    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                    {
                        {"Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>()}
                    });


                c.SwaggerDoc(version, new Info
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Version = version,
                    Description = "",
                    Contact = new Contact
                    {
                        Email = "Support@ABC.com",
                        Name = ""
                    }
                });
            });
```

Startup file

```cs
             app.
                //Swagger
                .UseSwagger()
                .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"./{_version}/swagger.json", Title);
                });
```

The version is app variable from Config file which will be filtered by CI/CD

Answer (score 2):

Swagger does not support Virtual Directory by default. Try and add  this to your Startup.cs

```
    app.UseSwagger(c =>

        {   
            c.RouteTemplate = "virtual_path/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });
     app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>

        {
            //Include virtual directory 
         c.RoutePrefix = "virtual_path";// add your virtual path here.

            c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"./v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix was following Killnines last comment to remove the preceding forward slash so that it looks like the following;

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
       options.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Your API v1");
      });
```